# Swift 2.0: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - Dictionary

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following code that used to work fine in Swift 1.2. Now, I've upgrade to Swift 2.0 and it no longer works with the following message:

> attributes:Dictionary -  Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
 var _text: NSString = self.text as NSString!
 var paragraphStyle : NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
 paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode =  lineBreakMode
 var attributes:Dictionary = [NSFontAttributeName:self.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle]
 var prefixTextSize: CGSize = _text.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)
```

Im unsure how to fix this as it used to work fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is `self.font` declared? My *guess* would be that it is an optional `NSFont?` and you need to unwrap it.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous without more context :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Martin R was correct. I fixed it by unwrapping self.font

```
var attributes:Dictionary = [NSFontAttributeName:self.font!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the type for the dictionary more clearly, if that's not the problem it might point the way (as @Martin suggests could be an optional requiring unwrapping).

For example:

```
var attributes: [String:NSObject] 
    = [NSFontAttributeName:self.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle]
```